# How to replay Wireshark captured packets?

Tags: wireshark, scapy, packet-sniffers, packet-capture

I have captured some packets in Wireshark and need to replay those again in any way.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=replay+pcap Note wireshark provides several [commandline programs](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/) that can select, split, combine, and alter the contents of pcap files so you could replay data partly the same as but partly different from what was captured.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending packets captured with Wireshark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21279666/sending-packets-captured-with-wireshark)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Wireshark wiki [Tools](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/wikis/Tools) page lists many packet capture related tools, among them some tools that can replay packets such as [Bit-Twist](http://bittwist.sourceforge.net/), [PlayCap](https://github.com/signal11/PlayCap), [Scapy](https://scapy.net/), [tcpreplay](http://tcpreplay.appneta.com/) and several others.

Comment: I'm still trying to find a suitable tool. the rules are simple.
1) must work. :)
2) must not require cygwin (which knocks a lot of them out)
3) must work on windows 10 if wireshark is installed (note that by default wireshark does not install the winpcap api by default!).
4) must actually be free. (also knocks out a lot of them)
5) must allow you to repeatedly retransmit the packets, ideally without limit.
5) must allow you to retransmit with the same timing they were originally sent at.  

still looking for something that does that all.

Comment: @Mr.Beeblebrox That's a lot of rules :-) ! Try [Ostinato](https://ostinato.org) - it should do all of them I believe. Specifically for (3) you will need Winpcap or Npcap; (4) - An old version v0.4 is available for free on the [Archives](https://ostinato.org/archives) page.

Disclosure: I'm the creator of Ostinato

Comment: I remember discarding that program, most likely because it was not free. and ostinato will replay the packets at the exact same timing?

Answer (score 1):

I just had to do this on a Windows machine.  Most all of the methods required a UNIX machine or cygwin.  Colasoft Packet Player worked great without having dependencies on other software or drivers.