# Scapy sets all packets to BROWSER and interates through IPs

Tags: python, networking, scapy

I am trying to replay a recorded packet traffic with edited Ips and Mac addresses. The appropriate packets were not reieved, so I checked what Scapy was creating by writing the produced packets to a file.Whenever I use this code:

```
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.utils import rdpcap
#This code reads packet data from the pcap file supplied, and then edits the packets.
pkts = rdpcap("Zeus.pcap")
for pkt in pkts:
    pkt[Ether].src = "00:E0:4C:00:02:42"
    pkt[Ether].dst = "00:E0:4C:01:08:99"
    pkt[IP].src = "169.254.162.71"
    pkt[IP].dst = "169.254.208.208"
    pkt[IP].chksum = None
    pkt[IP].payload.chksum = None
    wrpcap('ModifiedZeus.pcap', pkt, append=True)
```

Which is a derivative of the answer provided here:

[Sending packets from pcap with changed src/dst in scapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726881/sending-packets-from-pcap-with-changed-src-dst-in-scapy)

I get these packets:

[image: Wrong packets]

Excerpt from Zeus.pcap (The expected outcome is this packet file with changed source and destination addresses.)

[image]

**The Issue**
To my understanding, the Scapy code should reply what is in the packet file, with the updated ip,mac and checksums. Why does the code **only** send BROWSER protocol packets? And why is the **Source and Destination IP addresses wrong** in the output?

Comment: Whats the issue? You forgot to mention it or it's very unclear.

Comment: "The appropriate packets were not reieved" => What are these, exactly?

Comment: @Cukic0d Sorry, I have made the question clearer.

Comment: @RossJacobs The packets received were incorrect. They where of the wrong protocol and had the wrong Source and Destination IP addresses.

Comment: My guess is that there's an issue with the link layer. Maybe because you're using `append`.. Could be a bug. What happens if you add all the packets to a list then `wrpcap()` the list to a file?